# Given javascript syntax will do what?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started JavaScript programming last month, i know basic syntax like objects, functions, class, string, array, property.  Now i was puzzled on given syntax.

Syntax:

```
(function(){

 "use strict";

})();
```

My question is, why two parenthesis( one contains 'function' and another "empty" ) are included in the definition? can some one help me why we use this?.

Comment: ..we all love dogballs..

Comment: above link is very good...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a *self-invoking* function.

It pretty much is exactly that, a function which immediately gets called. To accomplish that, we **need** a *function expression*, not a *function declaration*. To achieve that, we can do certain things, one of those is, to put the whole expression in *parenthesis*

```
(function() {});
```

this statement creates a *function expression*. Now all we have left to do is, to invoke that function by appending additional *function parenthesis*, like we would do with any function

```
(function() {})();
```

You can also put the *function parenthesis* into the whole statement, it makes no difference

```
(function() {}());
```

Another option to bring a *function* into an *expression form* is by using `!` or `+` signs infront of it

```
!function(){}()
```

Anything goes, as long we create an expression, we can't invoke a *function declaration* like that

```
function foo(){}() // syntax error
```

Answer (score 2):

That will create an anonymous function and then immediately execute it.

In this case that function has a single line...`"use strict"`.

Answer (score 2):

That code doesn't have any net impact on the world.  What happens is:

- The parenthesized function is instantiated;
- The final `()` cause that function to be called;
- The "use strict" constant turns on "strict" mode;
- The function returns.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *self-invoked anonymous function* (or *immediately invoked function expression*, also known as IIFE), a pattern that in this case exists just to produce a closed scope.

Apparently, they don't want `"use strict";` turning on strict mode for the whole file, or when minified and concatenated to other files, turning on strict mode on included libraries, etc. Amazon had a problem with this a while back. Since then, it's been recommended best practice to keep `"use strict"` in function scope, and this function exists solely for that purpose.

Comment: I don't mean to pick on you but a popular alternative term is "immediately-invoked function expression" (IIFE), which is a bit more accurate since the function doesn't really invoke itself.

Comment: @Pointy I actually googled both expressions before writing the answer to see which would lead to more useful results, but you're right.

Comment: I called them that for quite a while before somebody asked me how exactly the function managed to execute itself :-)

Comment: @Pointy :O YOU'RE RIGHT!